# Book Recommendation on Probability Theory

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation

I've been reading Probability and Stochastic by E.Cinlar.But I feel hard to understand the new concepts in it because there is no motivation in the book.

So I was wondering if someone could recommend good books on probability theory with measure theory treatment and explanation of every basic concepts in probability theory.You can suppose that I have a background in real analysis from Folland.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probability : application and example by R. Durrett.

Comment: my preferred book on probability theory is *Probability & Measure Theory* of Robert Ash

Comment: @Surb Durrett is simply not great. Good as a reference but not to learn. OP needs a book with doable exercises and solutions to guide them.

Comment: @Snoop: This is your opinion, but certainly not mine. Moreover, you can find all solutions of the exercise somewhere on google...

Comment: *Probability with Martingales* by D. Williams and Feller’s volume 1 and 2 are the perfect companions, in my opinion. Chapter zero of the former is devoted to motivating the necessity of measure theory using calculations about the branching process as an example. Feller provides a rich intuitive and motivated yet rigorous treatment in both volumes (1 is for discrete RVs, and 2 is for continuous)

Comment: My suggestion is Elementary probability theory by David Stirzaker